# Internal Class Loader Error

Tags: java, classloader, powermock, jacoco

```
An internal error occurred during: "Analyzing coverage session TaskTest (Dec 4, 2015 3:14:27 PM)".
loader constraint violation: when resolving method 
"org.objectweb.asm.commons.JSRInlinerAdapter.<init>(ILorg/objectweb/asm/MethodVisitor;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)V" 
the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/loader/EquinoxClassLoader) 
of the current class, org/jacoco/core/internal/flow/MethodSanitizer, 
and the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/loader/EquinoxClassLoader) 
for resolved class, org/objectweb/asm/commons/JSRInlinerAdapter, 
have different Class objects for the type eb/asm/MethodVisitor;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)V 
used in the signature
```

Not too sure how this came about. I've had problems earlier in the project with Powermocks class loader dealing with Jacoco code coverage. But this doesn't appear to be happening due to powermock. If I'm reading this error right it looks like the same class loader is being loaded twice on the same class. Looking for this I have found articles pertaining to Linkage errors, but none have really been helpful with this.

I can run Junit tests just fine, the class it's testing runs just fine. Its purely when I try to run as a coverage report that I get this error.

Anyone seen anything like this?

Comment: Which version of powermock are you using? The just released 1.6.4 version have [some improvements in the Powermock's integration with Jacoco](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jayway/powermock/master/changelog.txt).